# Converting Silverlight to MVVM, a couple of issues

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm

I have a Silverlight project I'm converting to MVVM. It's my first time using the pattern and I'm struggling with something.

So basically I had this in the XAML code behind page:

```
 OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            if ((bool)ofd.ShowDialog())
            {
                _fileName = ofd.File.Name;
                FileStream fs = ofd.File.OpenRead();
                fileSize = (double)fs.Length;
                txtFileName.Text = fileName;
                index = 0;
                sendData = 0;

                byte[] file = new byte[fs.Length];
                fs.Read(file, 0, file.Length);
                //convertToChunks(file);

                prgUpload.Maximum = fileChunks.Count;
                prgUpload.Value = 0;
                //uploadChunks(index);
            }
```

And I cannot figure out how to wire it up to be able to use that in the model? I assume the viewmodel comes into play, but nothing is working.

Any thoughts?

Here is the work in progress XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Width="475" Height="340">
    <Canvas Margin="8,8,0,0" Background="White" Height="320" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="475">
        <Button Width="75" Canvas.Left="380" Canvas.Top="43" Content="Browse" x:Name="btnBrowse" />
        <TextBox Canvas.Left="25" IsReadOnly="True"  Canvas.Top="43" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="350" Text="{Binding Path=FileUploadName}" x:Name="txtFileName" />
        <ProgressBar Height="10" Width="350" Canvas.Left="25" Canvas.Top="99" x:Name="prgUpload" />

        <my:Label Content="Please select a file to upload"  Name="lblError" Canvas.Left="25" Canvas.Top="23" RenderTransformOrigin="0.133,-0.063" Width="220"/>
        <my:Label x:Name="lblProgress" Canvas.Left="25" Canvas.Top="78" RenderTransformOrigin="0.133,-0.063" Width="220"/>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

Basically I want it to fire after the user selects a file to upload.

Comment: When you want to fire the event? can you add your XAML where you want to wire it up with view model

Comment: Views bind to ViewModels which have a Model.  I believe you want to generate a new Model via your ViewModel with the data sent from your View.

Comment: I understand the view --> viewmodel --> model. But I'm just not getting the syntax or something to make it all work. Was hoping that someone could give me an example on each phase.

Comment: I cannot describe it better here than they can here: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/yougerthen/474/ and http://johnpapa.net/simple-viewmodel-locator-for-mvvm-the-patients-have-left-the-asylum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to fire a command this would do the work for you

```
<Button Width="75" Canvas.Left="380" Canvas.Top="43" Content="Browse" x:Name="btnBrowse" 
  Command={Binding OpenFileCommand} />
```

in your code behind Constructor for example

```
partial class MainWindow
{
   public MainWindow()
   {
     InitializeComponent();
     this.DataContext=new MainViewModel();
   }
}
```

and in your ViewModel

```
   public ICommand OpenFileCommand { get; set; }

   public MainViewModel()
   {
       OpenFileCommand = new RelayCommand(OpenDialog) { IsEnabled = true };

   }

   private void OpenDialog()
   {
       OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
       if ((bool)ofd.ShowDialog())
       {
           _fileName = ofd.File.Name;
           FileStream fs = ofd.File.OpenRead();
           fileSize = (double)fs.Length;
           //txtFileName.Text = fileName;// Apply Binding 
           index = 0;
           sendData = 0;

           byte[] file = new byte[fs.Length];
           fs.Read(file, 0, file.Length);
           //convertToChunks(file);

           prgUpload.Maximum = fileChunks.Count;
           prgUpload.Value = 0;
           //uploadChunks(index);
       }
   }
```

And the RelayCommand

```
public class RelayCommand:ICommand
{
   private bool _isEnabled;
   public bool IsEnabled
   {
       get { return _isEnabled; }
       set
       {
           if (value != _isEnabled)
           {
               _isEnabled = value;
               if (CanExecuteChanged != null)
               {
                   CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
               }
           }
       }
   }
   private Action _handler;
   public RelayCommand(Action handler)
   {
       _handler = handler;
   }


   public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
   {
       return IsEnabled;
   }

   public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

   public void Execute(object parameter)
   {
       _handler();
   }
}
```

in order to get the filename in your textbox  you have to bind the textbox to to the view model. so that it will appear on the UI and also implement INotifyPropertyChanged. Also Look at this it would be helpful [Silverlight MVVM](http://www.arrangeactassert.com/how-to-implement-mvvm-inotifychanged-and-icommand-in-a-silverlight-application/)